# The app stops working when any button is clicked, Error says that it couldn't find method

Tags: android, kotlin

I am learning Kotlin and recently have jumped upon a certain problem. As soon as I click on any button in my app, I get a similar error as shown in the title. Here's the complete error code

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method buRequestEvent(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'buRequest'
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:423)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:380)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5646)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22473)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

I have tried a lot of fixes given on other questions but most of them are in Java and I am programming in Kotlin. None of them have worked yet.

Here's the code of one of the buttons

from *MainActivity.kt*

```
 protected fun buRequestEvent(view: View){
        var userEmail = etEmail.text.toString()
        myRef.child("Users").child(splitString(userEmail)).child("Request").push().setValue(myEmail)
    }
```

I have a rough idea that the problem might be due to the imports in my project file so here's the list of the imports

from *MainActivity.kt*

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.HashMap
```

P.S. - I have checked the XML file, the button has an onClick attribute added to it

from *activity_main.xml*

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/buRequest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="buRequestEvent"
            android:text="REQUEST" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is , the `onclick` method should have `public` access modifier, so use

```
 public fun buRequestEvent(view: View){
        var userEmail = etEmail.text.toString()
        myRef.child("Users").child(splitString(userEmail)).child("Request").push().setValue(myEmail)
    }
```

From [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button#HandlingEvents)

- Be public      // violation here
- Return void
- Define a View as its only parameter (this will be the View that was clicked)